# Alcoholic beverage owned by a non religious jew over pesach?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, passover, chametz-leaven

There are many lists of kosher alcoholic beverages. When I walk into a random liqueur store, there is no way to know if any of the previous owners of the drinks were non religious jews. Being that alcoholic beverages are stored for a very long time, why don't I have to afraid that perhaps a non religious jew owned the drinks over Pesach?

Comment: Seems like a pretty farfetched concern. Maybe a non-Jew snuck into the store and injected pig juice in through the cork? There's always fantastical scenarios that are technically possible.

Comment: @DoubleAA farfetched… unless you know a distributor or the storeowner or the manufacturer is Jewish.

Comment: @msh210 If you know the store owner or manufacturer is Jewish then there's also no Safek since it's definitely prohibited.

Comment: @DoubleAA, ? Depends when it was there.

Comment: @msh210 Sure, but then you are potentially looking at his inventory flow to see if it's possibly permitted. This is simply not the case the OP was asking about.

Comment: @DoubleAA, anyway, I dispute the question's claim that "there is no way to know if any of the previous owners of the drinks were non religious jews". And if there *is* a way to know, a reasonable question is whether one must find out before buying.